# Relation between function integral and sum of function values.

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, ergodic-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function with period $T$,where $T$ is an irrational number,and the integral of $f$ over one period is $0$.

Can we conclude that $\sum_{k=0}^N f(k)$ is bounded?

Comment: Check [here](http://mathoverflow.net/q/150863/23297) for a counter-example.  This is a pretty interesting question, though, because the counter-example is not obvious.